How to resolve an asymmetric routing issue?
I have a network consisting of the following:
PfSense router with untagged network 10.1.0.0/23 and tagged VLAN 40 network of 10.1.40.0/24.
I have a wireless computer connected to the the 10.1.0.0 network with IP address 10.1.0.11
I have a linux server connected to router with two network cards with addresses 10.1.0.200 and 10.1.40.200 - IP addresses are assigned through DHCP from the router (more on this in a bit).
Problem
When I establish a ssh connection from wireless computer to the 10.1.0.200, I don't receive any dropped connections -- which makes sense since both client and server are on the same subnet.
When I establish a ssh connection from wireless computer (10.1.0.11) to 10.1.40.200, the connection is established initially, but within about 20-40 seconds the network connection drops and examining the PfSense logs, I get the following:
Default allow LAN to any rule (100000101)     10.1.1.11:60991     10.1.40.200:22    TCP:S
...
...
Default deny rule IPv4 (1000000103)|  10.1.1.11:60742|  10.1.40.200:22|TCP:PA
Default deny rule IPv4 (1000000103)|  10.1.1.11:60742|  10.1.40.200:22|TCP:A

Through connsulting the PfSense documentation (https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/troubleshooting/asymmetric-routing.html), this appears to be a case a asymmetric routing.  I wondering how to fix this issue.
Server routing table
As stated above the linux server has two network cards attached to two separate networks with IP addresses given out by dhcp.
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1.40: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:14:29:b2:d8:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.40.200/24 metric 1000 brd 10.1.40.255 scope global dynamic eth1.40
       valid_lft 6690sec preferred_lft 6690sec
3: eth1.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:d0:5d:0c:3f:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.0.200/23 metric 1000 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global dynamic eth1.0
       valid_lft 2496sec preferred_lft 2496sec

Because of this the routing table appears like the following (which I think is the source of the error):
default via 10.1.40.1 dev eth1.40 proto dhcp src 10.1.40.200 metric 1000
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth1.0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.200 metric 1000
10.1.0.0/23 dev eth1.0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.200 metric 1000
10.1.0.1 dev eth1.0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.0.200 metric 1000
10.1.40.0/24 dev eth1.40 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.40.200 metric 1000
10.1.40.1 dev eth1.40 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.40.200 metric 1000

So what I'm envisioning happening in this circumstance is connections from client (10.1.0.11) are passing through the router and routed through to the 10.1.40.0 network and received by the server on interface eth1.40. The server responds back to the client using the eth1.0 interface which I'm guessing isn't routed back through the router. The client then responds back to the server with these packets passing through the router (TCP:PA and TCP:A packets) which it seems the router is dropping.
Thinking about the problem a bit more, I'm not sure the best way to design things to prevent this from happening, other than just make the server available on one interface rather than two. I've contemplated changing the routing table, however I'm not exactly sure how I would change the server routing table to prevent such an issue.
Thanks for any input.

What does the server currently use for IP configuration, and does it need to be on both networks? (If you were to fix this from the server's side to no longer be asymmetric, that would automatically lose the advantage it has of being on the same network as the client...)

There are two options:

On the server, configure some kind of source-based routing; on Linux for IPv4 that means dealing with policy routing in which there are multiple independent routing tables.

One routing table would have only the routes related to eth1.0 (the local /23 route and the respective default route);
Another routing table would have only the routes related to eth1.40;
Policy-routing rules would select either table A or table B for each outgoing packet, based on which source address the packet has.

For example, if the outbound packet has the source address 10.1.40.200, the rule from 10.1.40.0/24 lookup 40 would select table 40 which would only have default via 10.1.40.1 dev eth1.40 but not the 10.1.0.0/23 dev eth1.0.
This might unfortunately be a bit annoying to automate. I think it could be done easiest by using the Linux "VRF" feature (assigning each interface to a separate VRF, and relying on the resulting 'l3mdev' magic rule), but I have never fully tried it myself.
The downside, though, is that as long as the client keeps contacting the server by its "faraway" address – that is, if the 10.1.0.0/23 clients keep talking to 10.1.40.200 and not to 10.1.0.200 – then this loses any advantage that your server might have of being in the 10.1.0.0/23 network. You might as well disconnect eth1.0 and leave the server talking on eth1.40.

So if that's acceptable, then I would just choose the simplest option of disconnecting eth1.0 and leaving the server on one network only.


Alternatively, allow asymmetric routing. All "established" TCP packets have the ACK flag, so if the firewall is set to allow those through, it'll permit the asymmetric flow (which indeed only goes through the router in one direction but direct in the other, so normally the firewall's "state" is never fully established).
(I think that might be what pfSense's "Sloppy" state matching does? I'm not sure.)
The advantage of this is that the flow from the server to the client does not contribute to the router's load at all – the client can e.g. download data at the full 1Gbps from the server's eth1.0 while your router's both interfaces remain (almost) completely free, aside from the relatively low amount of TCP ACKs.



Hey thanks for the extensive writeup.  I learned a lot from it.  I just went with the asymmetric routing option as this seemed the most straightforward

It is for TCP; but you might have some problems with UDP as the firewall might not be able to distinguish directions.

You are definitely correct with UDP as discovered when trying to perform some DNS lookups. I take it there is no "sloppy" workaround for UPD?

There isn't, as UDP packets don't have any state indication in themselves (no way to distinguish 'new' packets from 'reply' ones). You'd have to specifically allow e.g. "src port = 53" packets and so on.
